# Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘./router’ in ‘C:\HK\Vue-learning\testapp1\src’

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I am new to Vue js. I have installed a basic vue template and added a web pack for bundling. But when I use “webpack --config webpack.config.js” to build the app I am getting the following error.

**ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘./router’ in ‘C:\HK\Vue-learning\testapp1\src’
@ ./src/main.ts 2:0-30 7:12-18

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘./store’ in ‘C:\HK\Vue-learning\testapp1\src’
@ ./src/main.ts 3:0-28 8:11-16

ERROR in Error: Child compilation failed:
Entry module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘C:\HK\Vue-learning\testapp1\static\index.html’ in ‘C:\HK\Vue-learning\testapp1’:
Error: Can’t resolve ‘C:\HK\Vue-learning\testapp1\static\index.html’ in ‘C:\HK\Vue-learning\testapp1’

compiler.js:79 childCompiler.runAsChild
[testapp1]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16

Compiler.js:343 compile
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11

Compiler.js:681 hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:681:15

Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
[testapp1]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

Compiler.js:678 compilation.seal.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:678:31

Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
[testapp1]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

Compilation.js:1423 hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35

Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
[testapp1]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

Compilation.js:1414 hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1414:32

index.js:321 taskRunner.run
[testapp1]/[terser-webpack-plugin]/dist/index.js:321:9

TaskRunner.js:48 TaskRunner.run
[testapp1]/[terser-webpack-plugin]/dist/TaskRunner.js:48:7

index.js:227 TerserPlugin.optimizeFn
[testapp1]/[terser-webpack-plugin]/dist/index.js:227:18

Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
[testapp1]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

Compilation.js:1409 hooks.additionalAssets.callAsync.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1409:36

Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
[testapp1]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

Compilation.js:1405 hooks.optimizeTree.callAsync.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1405:32

Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
[testapp1]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

Compilation.js:1342 Compilation.seal
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1342:27

Compiler.js:675 compilation.finish.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:675:18

Compilation.js:1261 hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1261:4

Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
[testapp1]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

Compilation.js:1253 Compilation.finish
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1253:28

Compiler.js:672 hooks.make.callAsync.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:672:17

Compilation.js:1185 _addModuleChain
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1185:12

Compilation.js:1044 errorAndCallback.bail.err
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1044:6

Compilation.js:1075 moduleFactory.create
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1075:14

NormalModuleFactory.js:401 factory
[testapp1]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

Child html-webpack-plugin for “index.html”:

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\HK\Vue-learning\testapp1\static\index.html' in 'C:\HK\Vue-learning\testapp1'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! testapp1@0.1.0 build:prod: webpack --config webpack.config.js
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testapp1@0.1.0 build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-17T04_54_32_639Z-debug.log**

```
 webpack.config.js
------------------------
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const config = {
entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main.ts'),
mode: env,
output: {
publicPath: '/build',
},
optimization: {
splitChunks: {
  // Must be specified for HtmlWebpackPlugin to work correctly.
  // See: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/882
  chunks: 'all',
},
},
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    exclude: /node_modules/,
},
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: "ts-loader",
    options: {
        appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        transpileOnly: true
    }
},
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: "css-loader"
}
],
},
plugins: [
new VueLoaderPlugin(),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'),
  template: path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html'),
  inject: true,
}),
],
 };

module.exports = config;'
```

package.json

```
package.json

{
“name”: “testapp1”,
“version”: “0.1.0”,
“private”: true,
“scripts”: {
“serve”: “vue-cli-service serve”,
“build”: “vue-cli-service build”,
“build:prod”: “webpack --config webpack.config.js”,
“lint”: “vue-cli-service lint”
},
“dependencies”: {
“vue”: “^2.6.11”,
“vue-class-component”: “^7.2.2”,
“vue-property-decorator”: “^8.3.0”,
“vue-router”: “^3.1.5”,
“vuex”: “^3.1.2”
},
“devDependencies”: {
“@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin”: “^2.18.0”,
“@typescript-eslint/parser”: “^2.18.0”,
“@vue/cli-plugin-eslint”: “~4.2.0”,
“@vue/cli-plugin-router”: “~4.2.0”,
“@vue/cli-plugin-typescript”: “~4.2.0”,
“@vue/cli-plugin-vuex”: “~4.2.0”,
“@vue/cli-service”: “~4.2.0”,
“@vue/eslint-config-standard”: “^5.1.0”,
“@vue/eslint-config-typescript”: “^5.0.1”,
“eslint”: “^6.7.2”,
“eslint-plugin-import”: “^2.20.1”,
“eslint-plugin-node”: “^11.0.0”,
“eslint-plugin-promise”: “^4.2.1”,
“eslint-plugin-standard”: “^4.0.0”,
“eslint-plugin-vue”: “^6.1.2”,
“typescript”: “~3.7.5”,
“vue-template-compiler”: “^2.6.11”,
“vue-webpack”: “^1.10.2”,
“webpack-cli”: “^3.3.11”
},
“eslintConfig”: {
“root”: true,
“env”: {
“node”: true
},
“extends”: [
“plugin:vue/essential”,
“@vue/standard”,
“@vue/typescript/recommended”
],
“parserOptions”: {
“ecmaVersion”: 2020
},
“rules”: {}
},
“browserslist”: [
“> 1%”,
“last 2 versions”
]
}
```

Comment: Can you check path of your `router` file and `store` file if they are correct ?

Comment: the path is correct , its in src ->router -> index.ts and src ->store-> index.ts

Comment: can you try giving the full path like './router/index.ts`. (I dont think it will make an effect but just to be sure).

Comment: Do you have `index.html` in static folder as you are using `template: path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html')` in `webpack.config.js`

Comment: import router from './router' , 
import store from './store'           This is how i imported

Comment: I have a index.html in public folder

Comment: So you dont have a `static` folder or don't have an `index.html` in `static` folder

Comment: try replacing `template: path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html')` with `template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')`. and check if error changes

Comment: @NipunJain 
ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: BASE_URL is not defined

ERROR in   ReferenceError: BASE_URL is not defined

  - index.html:95
    C:/HK/Vue-learning/testapp1/public/index.html:95:11

  - index.html:102 module.exports
    C:/HK/Vue-learning/testapp1/public/index.html:102:3

  - index.js:284 Promise.resolve.then
  - index.js:284 Promise.resolve.then
    [testapp1]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:284:18

Comment: Previous errors got fixed